# Espresso's click action not work when i set a new OnTouchListener to button

Tags: android, android-espresso

i have this test

```
@Test
public void theTimeViewMustBeDisplayedAfterRecordButtonClick(){
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_record)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.tempo)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

but my `R.id.btn_record` has this OnTouchListener

```
public View.OnTouchListener getOnTouchListener(){
    return new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    status.setText(R.string.record_status_message);
                    status.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                    tempo.setAnimation(getPulse());
                    presenter.startRecord(getActivity().getFilesDir().getPath(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    status.setText(R.string.default_status_message);
                    status.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    tempo.clearAnimation();
                    presenter.stopRecord();

                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    };
}
```

when a run my tests, this test lock on this line

```
onView(withId(R.id.btn_record)).perform(click());
```

and nothing happens, but if a remove the OnTouchListener, the test runs normally, why? Any idea?

The complete code: https://github.com/faeldix/faeldix-android-microphone-mvp

Comment: break your case, and try..

Answer (score 0):

Using MotionEvent from [UiController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/UiController.html) can probably solve this issue, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/MotionEvents.html#sendDown(android.support.test.espresso.UiController,%20float[],%20float[]))

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can i use it? i really really dont undestand